# Wordpress blog: Text not wrapping around social media share button in Firefox

Tags: wordpress, plugins, text, media, word-wrap

I'm working on a wordpress blog which you can view at http://bethematchblog.org.  I've added a pinterest button plug-in which seems to work great in every browser EXCEPT firefox.  The text in every paragraph does not wrap around the button that I've added. The plug-in is called "Pin-it" and I'm using their customized CSS to position it into the page.  My code is as follows:

```
 .pin-it-btn-wrapper{
     width: 60px;
     float: right;  
     padding-top: 140px;
     margin-right: -66px;
  }
```

Is there any other information I should include?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest answer would be to put the pin social button inside the `.socialize-in-content`, or to wrap both in an external div and position the wrapper.